# looking for way to get mail to my application

Tags: c#, .net, email, imap, pop3

I need that my applicatiob will be able to get mail...
this is c# .net application that installed on windows server 2008,
So I want that one of the way to comunicate with the application will be through mail , so Someone will send mail to the application the application will parse the mail an do something accordingly

Any Idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create an SMTP Mail Server that listens on Port 25 and accept commands from a mail client.  A good understanding of how SMTP works and the basic commands clients send to a mail server.  You can find a list of commands and responses here:

http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/smtp.htm

You could then write a parser that interprets a command "do something accordingly" here.

Comment: but smtp server is only for sending mail not for getting mail , not?

Comment: An SMTP server would receive mail, a SMTP Client would send mail.

You could use the .NET SMTPMail class to send Mail to a server and the TCPListener class to build your Mail Server:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.71).aspx 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx

Comment: @MoShe - is there anything else that needs to be explained here? :-)

Comment: @DownVoter - Care to comment?

Comment: Writing your own SMTP server is a horrible idea. What about security? DNS configuration overhead? DOS attacks?

Comment: @PawelLesnikowski Writing your own SMTP server holds the same principal as writing any other type of server, i.e. HTTP, IRC or FTP. You are exposed to the exactly same risks as you mention. For instance, if you hosted an Exchange Mail Server you would be exposed to the exactly the same risks, i.e. a DOS attack.  I don't see how using a proprietary piece of software would prevent against such attacks.

Comment: @Darren The point is: that you don't need to write your own server!

Comment: @PawelLesnikowski - By using software that already exists still exposes the risks you mention, I honestly don't see how using another pre-built server application would prevent a DOS attack and security intrusions etc.  The OP states that they wish to perform custom parsing.  How would you implement that in a software application that may not provide an API?

Answer (score 1):

I have netter Idea, I create POP 3 client and connect it to POP 3 server like Gmail.

My POP 3 client is check the server every x time , and download all the massages , and send it to the main application through WCF